# Error caused by ThreeJSymbol

Tags: physics, numerical-value

I do not understand what causes non-physical answer in my code although I have read about the error.

I am also getting the following error, how could I fix the example error:

"CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression 0.0007342271125681172` should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers."

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
ne = 10;
nl = 20;
nL = 2*nl;
nst = 2 (2 nl + 1);
mvec1 = Table[-(nl - i), {i, 0, nL}]
mvec = Join[mvec1, mvec1]

 Lfxn[\[Mu]_] := Mod[\[Mu] - 1, nL] + 1
 sfxn[\[Mu]_] := Sign[\[Mu] - ( nst/2 + 0.5)]
 kdfxn[i_, j_] := If[i == j, 1, 0]
  Lvec = Table[i, {i, 1, nL}];
 svec = Table[sfxn[i\[Mu]], {i\[Mu], 1, nst}];
 avec = Table[kdfxn[i, j], {i, 1, ne}, {j, 1, nst}];

 Vc = Block[{l, L, m, m1, p}, 
 With[{code = 
  N[0.5 ThreeJSymbol[{l, 0}, {l, 0}, {L, 0}]^2 ThreeJSymbol[{l, 
  m}, {l, m1}, {L, -(m + m1)}] ThreeJSymbol[{l, -p}, {l, 
  p - (m + m1)}, {L, (m + m1)}] (2 l + 1)^2 (-1)^(
  p - (m + m1))]}, 
 Compile[{{l, _Integer}, {L, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}, {m1, \
 _Integer}, {p, _Integer}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]]];


 chmat = With[{Vcc = Vc, kkdfxn = (If[# == #2, 1, 0] &)}, 
  Compile[{{nl, _Integer}, {nL, _Integer}, {nst, _Integer}, {ne, \
 _Integer}, {mvec, _Real}, {Lvec, _Real}, {avec, _Real}, {svec, _Real}},
  Block[{ms, ms1, kf01, L0, tmp1, tmp2, m0, m10, p0, l0, tmp}, Table[
  ms = Compile`GetElement[svec, nms];
  ms1 = Compile`GetElement[svec, nms1];
  L0 = Compile`GetElement[Lvec, nL0];
  l0 = nl;

   tmp = 0.0;
    Do[
    m0 = Compile`GetElement[mvec, nm];
    m10 = Compile`GetElement[mvec, nm1];
    p0 = Compile`GetElement[mvec, nm3];

   tmp1 = Vcc[l0, L0, m0, m10, p0];

   kf01 = kkdfxn[ms, ms1];

   Do[
    tmp += (tmp1  kf01) Compile`GetElement[avec, j, 
    nm3] Compile`GetElement[avec, j, nm3 + nm1 - nm], {j, 1, ne}], {nm1, 1, 
   nst}, {nm,
   1, nst}, {nm3, 1, nst}];

   , {nms, 1, nst}, {nms1, 1, nst}, {nL0, 1, nL}]]

   , CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];

   chmat[nl, nL, nst, ne, mvec, Lvec, avec, svec]
```

Comment: Does your code work without all the Compile statements? If so, why not add in the Compiles one at a time to see where the compilation error occurs?

Comment: It was working when I had some other functions instead of ThreeJSymbols, I know the problem is with the way I am using ThreeJSymbol, but I am not sure how to fix it